# String Formatting in java to replace the array index with the pointed string element

Tags: java, string-formatting

We have to replace as follows Alibaba site china comparison best-Replacement array
{} is {4} online {3} shopping {} in {}-positional argument array

Output must be Alibaba is best online comparison shopping site in China.Please help me in getting so

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question. Maybe posting example of input and expected result would help.

Comment: What is this ? are trying to say that you need to position those array elements in String? make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MessageFormat like this

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String result = MessageFormat.format("{0} is {4} online {3} shopping {1} in {2}" ,
            "Alibaba" ,"site",  "china", "comparison", "best");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

it will output

```
Alibaba is best online comparison shopping site in china
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) and append the parameters you want to create a msg..

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String msgRaw = "Alibaba {0} {1} site {2} China";
    String[] appender = { "is the best", "online comparison shopping", "in" };
    String text = MessageFormat.format(msgRaw, appender);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

**Output**

> Alibaba is the best online comparison shopping site in China